# Facing unexpected tokken '?' error in fastify 4

Tags: node.js, fastify

I am working in node application, there I am using fastify but it not working as expected.

**Environment**,

> node : 13.14.0
>
> npm : 6.14.4

**package.json** file is

[image]

**index.ts** file

[image]

When running the application it throws an ***error*** as below,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As wrote in the [Fastify LTS statement](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/main/docs/Reference/LTS.md#schedule), fastify v4 support Node.js >= 14

That said, the fastify codebase uses nullish operator `??` and the optional chaining operator `?.` that are not supported by Node.js 13